# MYSQL making query case insensitive

Tags: mysql, django

I know mysql queries are case sensitive. But in one of my DB it's working as case insensitive. Both of the below queries are giving the same results

`Select username from auth_user where username='shivam'`

and

`Select username from auth_user where username='ShivaM'`

I have used this DB in my django project and I generally use icontains and iexact lookup for case insensitive queries but I'm not able to figure out the reason for above behaviour.

Comment: you need to check the database charset collation  or colomn charset collation with `SHOW CREATE TABLE auth_user`

Answer (score 0):

The default character set and collation are latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default. This means that if you search with col_name LIKE 'a%', you get all column values that start with A or a.

```
// this returns true
select 'A' like 'a'

// this returns false
select 'A' like binary 'a'


select * from user where email like binary 'a'
```

maybe this link is useful for you

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html